# Internal Server Error when changing chart font name via API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to update formatting of the charts using Sheets API's [`UpdateChartSpec`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateChartSpecRequest) request. 
However, the script returns the error:

> "API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Internal error encountered"

Here's the snippet of my code that raises the exception:

```
var request = [{
  'updateChartSpec': {
    'chartId': chart_id,
    'spec': {
      'fontName': 'Arial',
      'basicChart': {          //to update font name, it seems that chart type should be provided
        'chartType': 'BAR' 
      }
    }      
  }
}];

Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': request}, spreadsheet_id);
```

Can anybody tell, what's wrong with the request, if anything?

Comment: Usually you need to specify the `fields` in a request, to indicate the property that is being changed: `updateChartSpec: { chartId: "the id", spec: { fontName: "the new font" }, fields: "fontName" };`

Comment: Thank you, tehhowch, for your copmment! Yes, but for this specific request property fields is not needed - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateChartSpecRequest. I tried the request modified by you, and it is encountering the error of Invalid JSON payload . Still, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the "Samples" section on the Google Sheets API description, [you cannot perform a partial chart specification update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#edit_a_charts_properties) - you must replace the existing spec with a whole new spec.

If you just want to change a small bit of the current spec, then the simplest approach is to

1. Query the current `chartSpec`
2. Change the necessary bits
3. Issue the update with the (whole) modified spec.

In Apps Script this might be implemented as such:

```
function getChartSpecs(wkbkId) {
  const fields = "sheets(charts(chartId,spec),properties(sheetId,title))";
  var resp = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(wkbkId, { fields: fields });
  // return an object mapped by chartId, storing the chart spec and the host sheet.
  return resp.sheets.reduce(function (obj, sheet) {
    if (sheet.charts) {
      sheet.charts.forEach(function (chart) {
        obj[chart.chartId] = {
          spec: chart.spec,
          sheetName: sheet.properties.title,
          sheetId: sheet.properties.sheetId
        };
      });
    }
    return obj;
  }, {});
}
function makeChartUpdateRequest(chartId, newSpec) {
  return {
    updateChartSpec: {
      chartId: chartId,
      spec: newSpec
    }
  };
}
function setNewFontOnChart(newFontName, chartId, chartSpecs) {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const wbId = wb.getId();
  if (!chartSpecs)
    chartSpecs = getChartSpecs(wbId);

  var requests = [];
  if (!chartId) { // Update all charts
    requests = Object.keys(chartSpecs).map(function (id) {
      var chart = chartSpecs[id];
      chart.spec.fontName = newFontName;
      return makeChartUpdateRequest(id, chart.spec);
    });
  } else if (chartSpecs[chartId]) { // Update just one chart.
    chartSpecs[chartId].spec.fontName = newFontName;
    requests.push(makeChartUpdateRequest(chartId, chartSpecs[chartId].spec));
  } else {
    // oops, the given chartId is not valid.
  }
  if (requests.length) {
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: requests }, wbId);
  }
}
```

Useful links:

- [Partial Responses / "Fields"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#partial_responses)
- [APIs Explorer - spreadsheets#get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.get?spreadsheetId=YOUR%20WBID%20HERE&fields=sheets(charts(chartId%252Cspec)%252Cproperties(sheetId%252Ctitle))&_h=6&)
- [APIs Explorer - spreadsheets#batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate?spreadsheetId=YOUR+WBID+HERE&_h=1&resource=%257B%250A++%2522requests%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522updateChartSpec%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522chartId%2522%253A+%2522YOUR+CHARTID+HERE%2522%252C%250A++++++++%2522spec%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522fontName%2522%253A+%2522Roboto%2522%252C%250A++++++++++%2522basicChart%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%250A%257D&)
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)